# Need for Mutex while using Shared Memory (C++) for hardware applications

Tags: c++, memory, mutex, shared

I have a sensor that is writing data to shared memory in a thread at n Hz (say 10Hz=10 times per second). A separate thread is reading this data and using it to acquire some result. The frequency of the reader thread is different. It can be slower e.g 8 times a second or faster e.g 15 times a second depending on what is being calculated. The reader thread just reads the data from shared memory. It does not modify the data (only process it to get some result) and does not write anything to shared memory. The entire process works very neatly. I do not care about the synchronization since the reader just reads off what ever is in shared memory when it needs to (it polls for the data). If between two reads, the contents of the shared memory changes, the reader uses the new data. If between two reads the contents of the shared memory does not change (if the reader is much faster than the writer) then the reader just uses whatever data is in the shared memory.

Now my colleague is telling me to synchronize access to  shared memory using a mutex but I disagree. Reason is that if I use a mutex to control access, the frequency of the writer writing to shared memory will be somewhat reduced (when the reader thread has locked the mutex and writing). In the future we will have more reader threads and I am afraid that the frequency with which the writer thread can write to shared memory will decrease further since there will be two more threads competing for the mutex.

I know about race conditions etc. but I feel race conditions and the numerous examples given on SO as well other sites consider scenarios different from mine: Example when two threads are reading and processing the bank balance and one thread is slower or faster in reading and the balance amount ends up being erroneous...resulting in $2000 instead of $1000. However, in my case, the "bank balance" - the data to be shared is generated by a sensor. Any changes in the value are due to physical reasons and the data value to be shared will never jump such a big amount.

More details: The sensor is a distance measuring sensor. It measures distance 10 times in a second. Say the distance at t=1.0s was 10cm and it was written to memory. The reader reads the shared memory which says 10cm. Now if the real distance happens to change while the reader is reading or processing the data it will be 10.1cm or since the distance will never jump by large amounts. On the next poll, the reader will then read the distance of 10.1cm (assuming object is them stationary.) In this way, my writer thread can write as fast as possible without waiting for a mutex to be unlocked.

Is my reasoning flawed? The only problem I can imagine is if my writer and reader threads attempt to access memory at exactly the same time. But then, the scheduler is supposed to switch between instructions, right? That is, its just pseudo parallel processing, correct? This means they both cannot access the memory at the same time, correct?

Comment: Might want to add a TL;DR section to your question.

Comment: I think you are perfectly right, as long as you have only one thread writing you are safe.

Comment: In general you should use protection of the shared memory (e.g. a mutex). However, if you are coding for a specific platform and don't need portable code and the data types are simple (native) types, you may be able to do without mutex. That will require low level knowledge of your system.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this answer is supposed to be a comment, if it is, please let me know...

You could try to implement a circular buffer. This way, the writer has a pointer that just rotates through the buffer and keeps writing. The reader has the same, it just has to be 'behind' the writer one.

This means that when the writer writes some values, it has to increase the variable which states how much data is available. When the reader reads a sample, it has to reduce this variable. These operations have to be locked in a mutex. Although i++ and i-- are atomic operations, on a multicore system, this can still cause trouble, I found that out the hard way.

So yes, you do need mutexes, but because it's only needed on one variable, it won't slow down your entire program to much...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your implementation if you are using preemtive tasks (E.g Interrupts). Its possible that the reading thread is reading the value and during reading is interrupted by the writing thread. In your case I assume that the value is just a single integer therefore its not that crittical. Just make sure you only read the data once per execution in the reading thread (refer to atomic operations). If the value is larger than one register value. You can avoid a mutex by the usage of queues and multilevel buffers. But this is increasing your memory usage. In your case: I would suggest using tripple buffered memory if your data is larger than one integer. In this case you own three buffers the value is written in the first and after completion the buffer is switched with the seconed one while your reading thread is possible to read the 3rd one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is the reader can read at the same time as the variable is being written , the problem is only the write so I suggest you to use atomic operations for this write so you won't need mutex. The reads are atomics if the data is align (see [Read and Write atomic operation implementation in the Linux Kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289243/read-and-write-atomic-operation-implementation-in-the-linux-kernel)) , I'm not sure for the write operations , but maybe they're not so let's what we can do :

In C++, the STL provide some materials to garantee that operations are atomic see : http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic
In C, I found this type sig_atomic_t defined in the standard http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Atomic-Types.html that garantee atomic operations for reads and write , It should do the trick without mutex.

Comment: This is something very important and useful. Thanks. The type sig_atomic_t is new to me and seems very useful but in this case I am using a double. I am doing a memcpy to write the data so I will try to make it atomic. Have seen a page or two on how to make memcpy atomic.